# Can't get progress bar to work in python rich

Tags: python, progress-bar, rich

i'm trying to add a progress bar with rich to my code. However, while the code is running, the bar only updates to 100% after it's finished. Can I have any help? My code:

```
theme = Theme({'success': 'bold green',
              'error': 'bold red', 'enter': 'bold blue'})
console = Console(theme=(theme))
for i in track(range(1), description='Scraping'):
    global pfp
    global target_id
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
    begining_of_url = "https://lookup.guru/"
    whole_url = begining_of_url + str(target_id)
    driver.get(whole_url)
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//img")))
    images = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('img')
    for image in images:
        global pfp
        pfp = (image.get_attribute('src'))
        break
    if pfp == "a":
        console.print("User not found \n", style='error')
        userInput()
    img_data = requests.get(pfp).content
    with open('pfpimage.png', 'wb') as handler:
        handler.write(img_data)
    filePath = "pfpimage.png"
    searchUrl = 'https://yandex.com/images/search'
    files = {'upfile': ('blob', open(filePath, 'rb'), 'image/jpeg')}
    params = {'rpt': 'imageview', 'format': 'json',
              'request': '{"blocks":[{"block":"b-page_type_search-by-image__link"}]}'}
    response = requests.post(searchUrl, params=params, files=files)
    query_string = json.loads(response.content)[
                              'blocks'][0]['params']['url']
    img_search_url = searchUrl + '?' + query_string
    webbrowser.open(whole_url)
    webbrowser.open(img_search_url)
    console.print("Done!", style='success')
```

Edit:
For more clarity, I want the progressbar to update as it goes through each part of my code. There is only one url to scrape. For example it would start at 0%, and after `global pfp` the bar would change to x%

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that through the use of `for i in track(range(1), description='Scraping'):` the bar would only go to 100% when the loop had finished. By changing the `range()` value would make the code loop and would update the bar. To fix this issue I used another [rich](https://pypi.org/project/rich/) module called `Progress`.

By importing `Progress` and then modifying the code on the [Rich Documentation](https://rich.readthedocs.io/en/stable/progress.html) I got:

```
from rich.progress import Progress
import time

with Progress() as progress:

    task1 = progress.add_task("[red]Scraping", total=100)

    while not progress.finished:
        progress.update(task1, advance=0.5)
        time.sleep(0.5)
```

Essentially:

- At `task1 = progress.add_task("[red]Scraping", total=100)` a bar is created with a maximum value of 100
- The code indented under`while not progress.finished:` will loop until the bar is at 100%
- At `progress.update(task1, advance=0.5)` the bar's total will be increased by a value of 0.5.

Therefore, for my specific example, my end result code was:

```
theme = Theme({'success': 'bold green',
                  'error': 'bold red', 'enter': 'bold blue'})
console = Console(theme=(theme))
bartotal = 100

with Progress() as progress:
    task1 = progress.add_task("[magenta bold]Scraping...", total=bartotal)
    while not progress.finished:
                console.print("\nDeclaring global variables", style='success')
                global pfp
                progress.update(task1, advance=4)
                global target_id
                progress.update(task1, advance=4)
                console.print("\nSetting up Chrome driver", style='success')
                chrome_options = Options()
                progress.update(task1, advance=4)
                chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
                progress.update(task1, advance=4)
                driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
                progress.update(task1, advance=4)
                console.print("\nCreating url for lookup.guru",
                              style='success')
                begining_of_url = "https://lookup.guru/"
                progress.update(task1, advance=4)
                whole_url = begining_of_url + str(target_id)
                progress.update(task1, advance=4)
                driver.get(whole_url)
                progress.update(task1, advance=4)
                console.print(
                    "\nWaiting up to 10 seconds for lookup.guru to load", style='success')
                wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
                progress.update(task1, advance=4)
                wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(
                    (By.XPATH, "//img")))
                progress.update(task1, advance=4)
                console.print("\nScraping images", style='success')
                images = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('img')
                progress.update(task1, advance=4)
                for image in images:
                    global pfp
                    pfp = (image.get_attribute('src'))
                    break
                progress.update(task1, advance=4)
                if pfp == "a":
                    console.print("User not found \n", style='error')
                    userInput()
                progress.update(task1, advance=4)
                console.print(
                    "\nDownloading image to current directory", style='success')
                img_data = requests.get(pfp).content
                progress.update(task1, advance=4)
                with open('pfpimage.png', 'wb') as handler:
                    handler.write(img_data)
                progress.update(task1, advance=4)
                filePath = "pfpimage.png"
                progress.update(task1, advance=4)
                console.print("\nUploading to yandex.com", style='success')
                searchUrl = 'https://yandex.com/images/search'
                progress.update(task1, advance=4)
                files = {'upfile': ('blob', open(
                    filePath, 'rb'), 'image/jpeg')}
                progress.update(task1, advance=4)
                params = {'rpt': 'imageview', 'format': 'json',
                          'request': '{"blocks":[{"block":"b-page_type_search-by-image__link"}]}'}
                progress.update(task1, advance=4)
                response = requests.post(searchUrl, params=params, files=files)
                progress.update(task1, advance=4)
                query_string = json.loads(response.content)[
                                          'blocks'][0]['params']['url']
                progress.update(task1, advance=4)
                img_search_url = searchUrl + '?' + query_string
                progress.update(task1, advance=4)
                console.print("\nOpening lookup.guru", style='success')
                webbrowser.open(whole_url)
                progress.update(task1, advance=4)
                console.print("\nOpening yandex images", style='success')
                webbrowser.open(img_search_url)
                progress.update(task1, advance=4)
                console.print("\nDone!", style='success')
                progress.update(task1, advance=4)
```

Comment: Hi, I tested your example, but nothing is printed until the progress is done (bar showing 100%) even if it takes a long time to reach (I have no print for like 20 sec and then a 100% bar appears). Do you know where it can come from?

Answer (score 2):

In order to show a progress bar, Rich needs to know how may steps are involved and when you finish a step. The `track` function can get this information automatically from a sequence. You're using this in your example, but your sequence only has a single element so you go from 0 to 100% in a single step.

If you want to track progress of something you need a sequence that defines the work to be done. For instance if you had a list of urls to scrape, you might do something like this:

```py
from rich.progress import track
SCRAPE_URLS = ["https://example.org", "https://google.org", ...]
for url in track(SCRAPE_URLS):
    scrape(url)
```

The progress bar will advance for every URL.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm only scraping one url per user input in my code. By the looks of things this will have the same behavior as it only scrapes once. Thanks again :)